# Unable to add Hangouts button to HTML template within script tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-hangouts

On my index page, when I add a Hangouts button like below it is drawn & works as expected.

```
    <body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 m-body">
          <div class="m-header-text">
             Hello Friend
          </div>

          <g:hangout render="createhangout"></g:hangout>

          <div>
            <!-- Insert html view templates here -->
              <ui-view></ui-view>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- So on -->
   </body>
```

**But when I place it inside a template, which is displayed based on url route, then only the Hangouts button is not drawn & cannot be seen in UI.**

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
      <div class="col-md-12 m-Grid m-rowBg m-border">
        <div ng-repeat="peers in lop">
                        Hey {{peer.username}}
          Call Peer <g:hangout render="createhangout"></g:hangout>
        </div>
      </div>
  </script>
```

Could you please tell me why is it not being drawn 
& 
what should I do to get the button displayed? It would be of great help !

Using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and found a solution using Angular directives.

The problem rendering button with Google tag markup is that the rendering executes when the platform.js script loads, which is before Angular loads the template.

So a solution is to call Google API render function after Angular loaded the template. I did it creating an Angular custom directive with a link function :

```
hangoutButton.directive('hangoutButton', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div id="hangout-button"></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      gapi.hangout.render('hangout-button', {'render': 'createhangout'});
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can display it in a template with the custom element :

```
<div class="col-md-12 m-Grid m-rowBg m-border">
  <div ng-repeat="peers in lop">
    Hey {{peer.username}}
    Call Peer <hangout-button></hangout-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the angular controller to render with javascript instead of in html markup.  Try something like this:

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 m-body">
      <div class="m-header-text">
         Hello Friend
      </div>

      <div id="placeholder-div"></div>

      <div>
        <!-- Insert html view templates here -->
          <ui-view></ui-view>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- So on -->
```

In your controller:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div', { 'render': 'createhangout' });
}]);
```

Comment: Hello, this works with html markup also. The issue I am facing is that of when this is inside a angularJS template. Inside a template the hangouts button is not being rendered. Sorry,I think the post is little confusing. So put the placeholder-div in a template. & load that template with a change in url (say "/newHome"). In this template, the Hangout button is not being rendered.

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the  `/` from `id="/home.html"`

Comment: Hi Nelson, but that is not the issue. Actually, Only the Google hangouts button is not rendering in AngularJS template. So When I load this template "home.html", I expect the Google hangouts button also to show with all other elements. But somehow only this does not get created. So I wanted to know how to fix this issue. & if you could try this in an editor. It would be of great help to me :) ! If I find a solution, I would post here soon ! :)